# OxyPlot WPF not working with Button Click

Tags: wpf, buttonclick, oxyplot

I’m having some problems with OxyPlot that I have not been able to resolve through their documentation or other searches.  I’m working on a wpf application that will allow the user to open a .csv with a button-click event, then perform some math and report back some useful information.  I’d like to plot some of the generated data hence OxyPlot.  For some reason I cannot get the plot to populate, when the code that generates it, is within the button click event.  To illustrate here is a smaller example:
This code works (xaml):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="255" Margin="20,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="477">
        <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding ScatterModel}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

with this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        var tmp = new PlotModel { Title = "Scatter plot", Subtitle = "y = x" };
        var s2 = new LineSeries
        {
            StrokeThickness = 1,
            MarkerSize = 1,
            MarkerStroke = OxyColors.ForestGreen,
            MarkerType = MarkerType.Plus
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            s2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(i, i));
        }
        tmp.Series.Add(s2);
        this.ScatterModel = tmp;
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public PlotModel ScatterModel { get; set; }
```

And produces this:
[Plot Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBX8t.png)

But, without changing the xaml, if I copy/paste the code beneath the button click event:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = this;
        var tmp = new PlotModel { Title = "Scatter plot", Subtitle = "y = x" };
        var s2 = new LineSeries
        {
            StrokeThickness = 1,
            MarkerSize = 1,
            MarkerStroke = OxyColors.ForestGreen,
            MarkerType = MarkerType.Plus
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            s2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(i, i));
        }
        tmp.Series.Add(s2);
        this.ScatterModel = tmp;
    }
    public PlotModel ScatterModel { get; set; }
```

The plot never generates: [Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK8HE.png):

I’ve tried moving DataContext = this; back up to public MainWindow(), and vice-versa with InitializeComponent(); no change.  I’ve also tried defining

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindow/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

in the xaml but that throws an exception/infinite loop error during build.
Something simple I fear I'm not getting about OxyPlot implementation?

Thanks!
CSMDakota

Comment: It has nothing to do with the OxyPlot. You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so your `ScatterModel` will get updated after the Button Click. The loop comes from the line `<local:MainWindow/>`. In MVVM it would be `<local:ViewModel/>`.

Answer (score 3):

`INotifyPropertyChanged` keeps your view in sync with the program's state. One way to do this is by implementing a `ViewModel` (the MVVM pattern).

So let's create one. `ViewModelBase` introduces `OnPropertyChanged()`, the method that updates `ScatterModel`.

**ViewModels.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using OxyPlot;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private PlotModel _scatterModel;
        public PlotModel ScatterModel
        {
            get { return _scatterModel; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _scatterModel)
                {
                    _scatterModel = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propName = null)
        {
            // C#6.O
            // PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

In **MainWindow.xaml** you can now add

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tmp = new PlotModel { Title = "Scatter plot", Subtitle = "y = x" };
        var s2 = new LineSeries
        {
            StrokeThickness = 1,
            MarkerSize = 1,
            MarkerStroke = OxyColors.ForestGreen,
            MarkerType = MarkerType.Plus
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            s2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(i, i));
        }
        tmp.Series.Add(s2);
        ViewModel.ScatterModel = tmp;
    }

    // C#6.O
    // public ViewModel ViewModel => (ViewModel)DataContext;
    public ViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (ViewModel)DataContext; }
    }
}
```

Note we're no longer setting `DataContext = this`, which is considered bad practice. In this case the `ViewModel` is small, but as a program grows this way of structuring pays off.

Comment: Funk,  Excellent!  Thank you for the detailed answer, I followed your instructions and it is working now as intended.  Before I go back over to my main program I will make sure I understand what you did here, I still need to study it carefully.  Thanks!